# System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission' failed

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7, web-config

I already have my web.config file set to be full trust, so why am I still getting this error?

The site works fine under Mono .NET and the built in .NET webserver, but not IIS 7.

```
<system.web>
    <!-- trust level-->
    <securityPolicy>
      <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal" />
      <trustLevel name="High" policyFile="web_hightrust.config" />
      <trustLevel name="Medium" policyFile="web_mediumtrust.config" />
      <trustLevel name="Low" policyFile="web_lowtrust.config" />
      <trustLevel name="Minimal" policyFile="web_minimaltrust.config"/>
    </securityPolicy>
    <trust
       level="Full"
       originUrl=""
       processRequestInApplicationTrust="true"
   />

   ...
   </system.web>
```